# Dynamically Firing A gTag Event with Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I have a script that fires a dynamic gTag.js adwords conversion based on various user interactions taken on that page. This worked fine when I had gTag.js installed. However I recently upgraded to Google Tag Manager and now my code:

```
gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to':'Dynamic Bits Here'});
```

Is throwing an error. How can I convert this to be picked up by Google Tag Manager? I've tried pushing to the dataLayer directly with:

```
 window.dataLayer.push('event','conversion', {'send_to':'Dynamic Bits Here'});
```

However Adwords does not pick that up as a conversion. What I don't want to do is have to install a adwords conversion tracker in tag manager for every conversion as there are a ton of them.

Should I just keep gTag.js installed alongside tag manager???

Answer (score 0):

If gtag is already installed and works fine for you, then you can just leave it, especially if you use only Google tags - gtag is build to deploy all kinds of Google tracking, and running both gtag and GTM is a lot of Javascript for essentially the same purpose.

GTM does not by itself send data to Google Ads without a respective tag.

However there is usually no need to install multiple Google Ads tags in GTM. What you usually would do is to create variables in GTM that pick up the dynamic bits, and then plop the variables into the Google Ads tag. So instead of having one tag for every conversion, you have a single tag that is dynamically configured depending on the values pushed to the datalayer.

Comment: I'll have too look into the variable aspect I saw that, but have not researched it much. Is other than having some code bloat would there be any issue in running both gtag and GTM simultaneously until I get the GTM logistics figured out?